# Degree of an intersection of two affine hypersurfcaes is bounded by the product of their degrees?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Suppose $f, g$ are two polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, .., x_n]$. Does anyone know a reference for the fact that
$$
\deg V(f) \cap V(g) \leq \deg f \cdot \deg g
$$
by any chance? I can only find reference for projective varieties, and I just wanted to make sure it holds for the affine case as well... Thank you!

ps here $V(f) = \\{ p \in \mathbb{A}^n: f(p)= 0 \\}$

Comment: Assuming you have perfectly set up the notion of degree already, just take projective closures of everything and use the projective version. It's not so usual to ask about this - what is your goal here?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I just wanted to bound the degree of an affine variety defined by some equations, by the product of their degrees. I thought if I could figure out for two then I could figure out the rest

Comment: That really ought to go in your question - that's much more interesting than the question you've asked and it would probably get a bit of a different response.